# How to override a method when a button is tapped?

Tags: java, android, button, overriding

I was thinking of creating a button that when tapped can disable the phone back button. I wanted to be able to enable it back again by pressing another button. However, the way that I found to disable the back button was with an override. Could somebody lend me a hand on how I could do that? Thanks!

What I tried was to put the override inside the button listener and onClick method, but it highland the override in red. I then tried putting the override in a different class and then calling the class when the the button is tapped.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, but for anyone wondering the same thing, I'll post what I did. I implemented the following code inside MainActivity.class with the buttons:

```
private boolean backButtonEnabled = true;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (backButtonEnabled) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void disableBackButton() {
        backButtonEnabled = false;
    }

    public void enableBackButton() {
        backButtonEnabled = true;
    }
```